# Simple Rails Minitest case blowing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

This is a pretty simple case using minitest and a controller test. It goes something like this:

```
# words_controller_test.rb
class WordTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  it "should get random" do
    get words_random_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end

# test_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end


# word_controller.rb
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def random
    @word = Word.random
  end
end


 # word.rb (model)
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  validates :eng, presence: true
  validates :ned, presence: true

  def self.random
    Word.all.sample
  end
end
```

This works correctly when I run the rails server (in either dev or test mode) and visit /word/random

When I run this with `rails test` I get this wild error

```
~/m/p/r/railstestdemo (master →☡) rails test
Run options: --seed 33448

# Running:

.....Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    19: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    18: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    17: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    16: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    15: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    14: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    13: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    12: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    11: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    10: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
     9: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
     8: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
     7: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
     6: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
     5: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     4: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     3: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     2: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     1: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump'
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump': no _dump_data is defined for class Binding (TypeError)
    25: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    24: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    23: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    22: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    21: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    20: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    19: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    11: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     9: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     7: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     6: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
     5: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
     4: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
     3: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
     2: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server': DRb::DRbServerNotFound (DRb::DRbServerNotFound)
    25: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    24: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    23: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    22: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    21: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    20: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    19: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    11: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     9: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     7: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     6: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
     5: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
     4: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
     3: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
     2: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server': DRb::DRbServerNotFound (DRb::DRbConnError)
    11: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    10: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
     9: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
     8: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
     7: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
     6: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     5: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
     4: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
     3: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in start'
     2: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:97:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
     1: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:97:in `each'
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in start': undefined method `exception=' for #<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    1: from /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:145:in `run'
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:118:in `shutdown': Queue not empty, but all workers have finished. This probably means that a worker crashed and 1 tests were missed. (RuntimeError)
~/m/p/r/railstestdemo (master →☡)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very misleading error that I encountered the other day too.

Try downgrading Minitest to 5.13.0.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38424

You may also have a fixture that is missing data so be sure to check for that as well. In my case, I had added a validation for a column but didn't add it to the fixture data and got back the same error you saw.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38342

Comment: That fixed it for me! Thanks